# Probability of randomly selecting real number $k \le 1$ from interval $(0,3]$ is $0.5$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X:S \to (0,3]$ be a continuous, uniform random variable. Then, according to its cumulative probability function, the probability of selecting a real number $k \le 1$ is given by

$$ F(1) = \frac{1-0}{3-0} = \frac{1}{3} = 0.\bar 3 \approx 33.33 \% $$

In turn, this implies the probabiltiy of selecting a real number in $(1,3]$ is $1 - 0.\bar 3 = 0.\bar 6 \approx 66.66 \% $.

However, there exists a bijection $f:(0,1] \leftrightarrow (1,3]$, as evidenced by the following geometric proof

[image]

As you can see above, there is a unique ray proceeding from the uppermost vertex that pairs every real number in $(0,1]$ with a real number in $(1,3]$ and vice versa. This bijection implies both sets $(0,1]$ and $(1,3]$ have the same cardinality. In other words, both sets have same number of elements, and each element corresponds to a distinct event. If both sets contain the same number of events and every event is equally likely to occur, then I should be just as likely to select a real number from $(0,1]$ as I am from $(1,3]$.

Why then is the probability of selecting $k \le 1$ not $0.5 = 50 \%$?

Can someone help me resolve this paradox?

I did find a post with a nearly identical quesiton [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497781/probability-of-randomly-selecting-a-random-real-number?rq=1), but I find the answer (to part $1$) to be unclear.

**EDIT:** I am getting a lot of responses that resolve the paradox by invoking measure theory, but I have not been exposed to measure theory. Is there a simpler, more intuitive way of resolving this, or am I forced to learn measure theory?

Comment: For a continuous random variable $X$, the probability that $X=c$ is zero, for any real number $c.$ One does not get probabilities of an event by adding up the probabilities of the points in the event.

Comment: @coffeemath I am **not** computing the probability that $X = c$. Rather, I am computing the probability that $X \le c$, which is given by a cumulative probability function (cdf). For a continuous, uniform random variable, the cdf is defined as $F(X \le c) = \frac{c - \alpha}{\beta - \alpha}$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are the least and greatest values of $X$, respectively. See the wiki for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution

Comment: While you don't compute $P(X = c)$, The fact that the probability of $X$ hitting any individual point is 0 is why it does not matter that there is a bijection between (0, 1] and (1, 3]: bijections match points to points, but on an uncountable space with 0 probability on every point, why does the bijection matter?

Comment: @daisies Each point in $(0,3]$ corresponds to a distinct event. My understanding is that the probability of each distinct point is *not* $0$ as you say; rather, it is an infinitesimal (i.e. appraoching $0$ in the limit). In accordance with the third "additivity" axiom of probability theory, the cdf effectively sums an infinite number of infinitesimals along a given interval to find the probability of an event corresponding to $X \le k$. A bijection mathing points to points demonstrates that the number of events in $(0,1]$ is the same as in $(1,3]$, and we know all events have the same density.

Comment: If you are working in the usual settings (e.g. a probability is a real number in $[0, 1]$) then a probability can not be an infinitesimal, as there are no infinitesimals in $[0, 1]$. In the limit sense, if you mean that $\lim_{\delta \to 0}P(X \in [x - \delta, x + \delta]) = 0$, this agrees with the idea that $P(X = x) = 0$; technically speaking the CDF is not "summing" anything; the closest thing to that interpretation is that it is an integral over a constant density. Also finally note that the third law applies only to countable sums, which is why this is not a paradox that $P(X = x) = 0$.

Comment: The thing about sums and integrals matters in the following sense: $\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty x_i = \Sigma_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)$ for bijective $f$ when the sum converges absolutely, since it just reorders the sum. But it is not true that $\int x = \int f(x)$ for bijective $f$. Again, this is morally related to finite vs countable vs uncountable additive for probability measures.

Comment: Strictly speaking, an integral (and in probability we almost always are speaking of the Lebesgue integral) is not really the same as a sum over infinitesimals. I guess you could probably make this work in some nonstandard setting, but I am not sure; I additionally agree that $P(X \in I) > 0$ for any interval $I$ larger than a point, but $P(X = x)$ for any particular $x \in I$ is 0. Probabilities are, by definition, real numbers and not infinitesimals.

Comment: @daisies For one, please note the probability of selecting a real number in some interval *cannot* be zero; otherwise, it would be impossible to select any real number at all. Secondly, the cdf is indeed summing something... it is integrating over a curve, summing an infinite number of infinitesimal areas corresponding to the probability densities of events. The third law directly relates to the cdf of a continuous random variable because the cdf of such a variable is derived by breaking up the sum into discrete parts and then computing in the limit.

Comment: @daisies I understand your point about probabilites being real numbers and not infinitesimals. But... if every distinct real number in any given interval has probabiltiy $0$, then how does *any* real number become the result of an experiment, once performed??? For the experiment to be performed and result in a real number, that real number in question *must* have probability $> 0$; otherwise, it *cannot* occur, by definition. So, probability must be $>0$, however, it must be a number closer to $0$ than any other number. Hence, an infinitesimal.

Comment: Impossible and probability 0 are (sort of) different. I *could* get $X = 1.5$ on the dot, it just happens with probability 0, which is different from impossible, e.g. getting $X = 100$ when $X$ is uniform on $[0, 3]$ like it is here. The somewhat weird part is that we, as humans, can't run an experiment that is the same as realizing $X$: we only have finite precision, after all. So where is the experiment? There is none. If this makes you feel uneasy because of physical intuition, the issue is with moreso with identifying our universe with $\mathbb R^3$, not $P(X = x) = 0$.

Comment: We may have instrusments with finite precision, but that does not imply a precise real number does not exist whenever an experiment is performed. In any case, I will have to give some more thought and research to the possible distinction between probability and possibility. I'm not sure the distinction you're making is logical.

Comment: You might like reading this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/8mcz8y/notions_of_impossible_in_probability_theory/

Comment: @daisies thank you for taking the time to consider my questions, debate with me, and offer some resources. I realize I can be a little stubborn, but you have given me some interesting ideas to ponder. please leave an answer if you feel you've properly addressed the questions. at the very least I will leave an upvote. thanks again

Comment: You have a misunderstanding between two notions of assigning “size” to sets: the first is the notion of cardinalilty and the second is the notion of measure. All non-trivial intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality but their measures are all different (for an interval $(a,b]$, the measure is always $b-a$ but $(a,b]$ and $(c,d]$ are always in bijection.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty I have not learned measure theory. Is there a way you could resolve this paradox in simple, intuitive language, or am I forced to learn measure theory?

Comment: For the purposes of your question, the word "measure" in that comment could just be replaced with the word "length".  The fact is that any admissible bijection between $(0,1]$ and $(1,3]$ will "stretch" the interval somewhere; for instance, your geometric bijection is analytically given by $x \mapsto 2x+1$.  That $2x$ is the source of the stretch, so it doesn't preserve "length".  (this is also why integration be substitution must content at least naively with the $dx$ factor, because it encodes "length," so any map that doesn't preserve length must be accounted for)

Comment: I do see you talking about "infinitesimal length" at various points.  Like most non-standard tools, this one is only useful if you use it correctly.  For instance, the interval $(r, r+\varepsilon]$ has length $\varepsilon$.  Under your geometric bijection, this interval becomes $(1+2r, 1+2r+2\varepsilon]$, which has length $2\varepsilon$.  Both of these are infinitesimals, but they have different sizes.  The second is twice as big as the former.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks, yeah i am starting to get the picture, i think

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to say that @daisies did a great job engaging your question! Your bijection picture is really good, HOWEVER you have to deal with more than just points. Points are "length zero intervals," and so you should consider intervals of all lengths. When given a probability density function $f$, you should think of it on all such intervals, and more generally "nice" subsets of the reals. In other words, the density $f_X$ is a thing that lets you say $$P(X \in A) = \int_{x \in A} f_X(x) dx$$ for "nice" subsets $A$. In particular, we get the density by differentiating the cumulative distribution function $$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x).$$

In your picture, what we are doing is stretching the interval $[0,1]$ so that it looks like the interval $[0,3]$. If we call the bijection in the picture $g : [0,1] \to [0,3]$, then we can write it as $g(x) = 3x$. Now say that $Y$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and so has density $f_Y(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$ and zero elsewhere, and has cumulative density function $F_Y(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$. Meanwhile,if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,3]$, then the cumulative probability function for $X$ on $[0,3]$ can be written as
$$ F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(g(Y) \leq x)$$
since your picture shows that any outcome for $X$ can be uniquely obtained as $g$ applied to some outcome for $Y$. Since $g$ is invertible, we can relate $F_X$ on $[0,3]$ to $F_Y$ on $[0,1]$ and get $$F_X(x) = P(Y \leq g^{-1}(x)) = F_Y(g^{-1}(x)) = F_Y(\frac{1}{3}x) = \frac{1}{3} x.$$

Now, since the density function is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function, we have $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{3}$. Moreover, we have
$$ P(X \leq 1) = P(Y \leq g^{-1}(1)) = P(Y \leq \frac{1}{3}) = \frac{1}{3}.$$

I hope this helps.

P.S. Here's a quick proof that the probability $P(Y = a)$ cannot be positive for any fixed $a \in [0,1]$, contrary to one of your comments. Since $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, it doesn't matter which point $a$ I pick, the probabilities must all be the same constant, $c > 0$. However, there are infinitely many points $a \in [0,1]$, and the countable additive of probabilities means that if we pick any (countably) infinite collection $A = \{a_1, a_2,\ldots\}$, then $$P(Y \in A) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty P(Y = a) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty c = \infty.$$ But probabilities are required to be one on the whole space as well as monotone, so this is implies $P(Y \in [0,1]) \geq P(Y \in A)$ which is bigger than one [citation needed]. Probabilities are *not* required to be *uncountably* additive, so this doesn't show that the probability of a point *can't* be zero, merely that we will need more tools than just addition (i.e. integration theory).

Comment: curious to know your thoughts: although there is a bijection between $(0,1]$ and $(1,3]$, this is irrelevant because when we integrate over a density function and find the probability of randomly selecting a real in either interval, say $(0,1]$, we are adding the probability masses of an infinite number of sub-intervals in $(0,1]$, **each having non-zero but infinitesimal length.** Thus, anything implied by the $1-1$ correspondence from points to points becomes moot because we're not dealing with "length zero intervals" but dealing with sub-intervals of non-zero (albeit infinitesimal) length.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy It's possible that this is a meaningful thing to do, however it would not be the standard approach since it openly uses infinitesimal analysis. "Non-standard analysis" is a way to rigorously work with these notions, but I am not familiar with it. In the standard approaches of Riemann, Lebesgue, and Stieltjes integrals, we do not deal with infinitesimals

Comment: +1 but i don't really feel like this resolves the paradox. thanks for your contribution though

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy the "paradox" comes from the non-rigorous idea that we are adding up "infinitesimals". We tend to tell students that we are adding up the probabilities at the points and that the integral handles that for us, but this is a white lie. In the standard (Riemann) approach, you are NOT adding up infinitely many infinitesimals, because _there are no infinitesimals_. Rather, you are doing _finite approximation_ by using positive length intervals, and then seeing how your approximation behaves as you make the lengths smaller and smaller. You may want to refresh your integral calculus

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that integration over a density function is *not* adding up probabilities at points, and now that I consider this more intently I see why the 1-1 correspondence between points in $(0,1]$ and $(1,3]$ is irrelevant. However, an integral indeed adds up infinitely many infinitesimals. An infinitesimal is a non-zero, indefinitely small value approaching zero. In integration, each infinitesimal is a portion of the (signed) area between a function $f$ and $x$-axis obtained by multiplying $f(x)$ by a positive-length interval that is approaching $0$ (but never is $0$) in the limit.

Comment: In the classical theory of integration, _there are no infinitesimals_, so an integral is not adding up infinitely many infinitesimals. To make sense of infinitesimals requires a nonstandard analysis. However, it just so happens that a friend of mine pointed me to a text on probability using nonstandard analysis: https://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/nsa/o.pdf "Radically Elementary Probability and Statistics"

Comment: Thanks! i will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

> Let $X:S\to(0,3]$ be a continuous, uniform random variable.

There is one very "simple" reason why the cumulative probability function $F_X$ of this variable satisfies the equation $F_X(1) = \frac13$:
that's how a continuous **uniform** random variable is defined.

Specifically, for a **uniform** continuous random variable,
the probability of generating a number in any particular interval is exactly proportional to the length of the interval, provided the interval is between the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of the random variable's values.

And the length of an interval $(a,b]$ is defined as $b - a$.
(That's also the length of $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$, and $[a,b]$.)

In general, for a random variable $X:S\to(0,3]$,
you can make value of $F_X(1)$ be $\frac12$ if you want, but only by making
$X$ have a non-uniform distribution on $(0,3]$.
You could also make $F_X(1)$ have the value $\frac14$, or $\frac{17}{101}$,
or $\frac\pi5$, just by choosing the distribution.

The number of points in the interval is not involved in the definition of the probability in any way, because the definition completely ignores the number of points.

I put "simple" in quotation marks back at the beginning, because in order to fully understand a continuous uniform random variable in the way a mathematician would, you should know measure theory, which can take quite a while to digest. But there are a lot of things you can learn about probability theory without that deep understanding, and many of them really are this simple.